# Выполнение php как будто из другого места

Tags: php, git

Можно ли выполнить shell_exec() как-будто в и другого места?
Например, мне нужно получить sell_exec('git status') чтобы были пути полностью прописаны ко всем файлам

Comment: а-ля рабочую папку указать что ли (`chdir/getcwd`)? параметры git этого не позволяют?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 shell_exec('cd dir && git status')
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать функцию [`proc_open`](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.proc-open.php), там чуть больше заморочек, но есть 4й параметр - рабочая директория